# Tricks to mask the burnt flour taste

Tags: frying, flour

I fried some chicken in some rice flour and most of it turned out just fine ( I highly recommend rice flour over AP if you're pan frying).  A couple of pieces were a little blacker than I wanted.  Does anyone have any tricks to take the bitter taste out?  Like acidity/fat, etc.?

Comment: Salt is the normal bitter-masker, and also goes well on fried, well, anything. Never tried to mask burnt with it, though. I assume you've already scraped off the burnt bits?

Comment: Naturally. I didn't expect a cure all or anything. Just if anyone had any tips and tricks they use if they over-fry something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Salt.** 
Salt masks bitter flavors. However, (and unfortunately), the burnt flavor is not something easily masked. It's a typical flavor you might find in grilled meats, but not so much in breads and fried items.

**You could also mask the burnt flour taste by refrying.** Scrape off the burnt bits if you can. Change your oil, and refry the chicken. It's the best bet for eliminating that burnt flavor.

Comment: I bake, I fry, I cook... But I'm really a good guy when all is said and done. :)